# Use a scrollview to zoom an image in Xcode 11 avoiding the "Ambiguous Content Size" AutoLayout error

Tags: swift, image, autolayout, scrollview, zooming

My question is about the auto layout problem with scrollviews.

I'm just trying to add a scrollView on the storyboard, with its own constraints to the superView, but without any subviews inside it, and add an imageView inside it ONCE THE APP IS RUNNING. But with the "ambiguous content size" error on storyboard, autoLayout does not work on the scrollView, even if we uncheck the option "check of ambiguity". And IF I APPLY THE SOLUTION of adding a contentView to the scrollView, and pinning it with all those extra constraints, I ca still pinch and zoom the image inside the scrollView, but LOSE THE ABILITY TO PAN, whether the viewForZoom be the contentView or the added ImageView. If the ContentView is an imageView I have the same problem. Can zoom, can't pan.

Also, can anybody explain to me why this nonsensical "ambiguous scolding content error" is triggered in this Xcode version when the ScrollView has no content? Why do we need to pin a contentView with two redundant constraints, often to the scrollView's superview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interface Builder / Storyboard has no way of knowing that you will be adding subview(s) and constraints at run-time.

So, it is telling you that your **current layout** has an Ambiguous Content Size.

Would it be better to not show the message if the scroll view has no content? Maybe... but even though it is showing a design error, that doesn't mean you ***must*** fix it.

If you really want to get rid of the warning/error, couple options:

1) Add your imageView (with proper constraints) in Storyboard, and set the `.image` property at run-time.

2) Add a subview (with proper constraints) in Storyboard, and remove that view in `viewdidLoad()` before adding the imageView.

---

**Edit**

Here's a simple example: https://github.com/DonMag/ZoomTest

In IB / Storyboard, I added a `UIScrollView` and set only the width, height, centerX and centerY constraints, so Storyboard tells me **Ambiguous Content Size**.

In `viewDidLoad`, I add a `UIImageView`, set proper constraints, set scroll view delegate and min/max zoom scale.

---

**Edit 2**

Results using a `256 x 256` image, and constraining the scroll view to fill the parent view (scroll view background is cyan)...

On load - zoomScale == 1:

[image]

On load - zoomScale == 1 - rotated:

[image]

zoomScale = approximately 1.5 (just wide enough to fit):

[image]

zoomScale = approximately 1.5 - after rotation:

[image]

zoomScale == 5 - panned to top-left:

[image]

zoomScale == 5 - panned to top-left - after rotation:

[image]

zoomScale == 5 - panned to lower-right:

[image]

zoomScale == 5 - panned to lower-right - after rotation:

[image]

Comment: Have you actually achieve this? Because once you get that "error", AutoLayout no longer deals with that scrollView, and rotation is dysfunctional. If you have achieved it, would you be so kind to share the project?

Comment: @Hikarus - check my edited answer. I added a sample project on GitHub.

Comment: I've modified the constraints so that the scrollview is as big as the superView (which is what I'm aiming for) but Autolayout fails after rotation, and the imageView no longer takes up the whole scrollView content after rotating to horizontal. I just need a simple example with Autolayout working on a full-screen size scrollview with a zoomable image.

Comment: @Hikarus - first... are you saying that when you add a `UIImageView` to the scroll view in Storyboard - setting proper constraints to get rid of the *Ambiguous* warnings - everything works the way you want? If so, what constraints are you using? If not, then maybe you need to better explain what is ***not*** working the way you expect? I added screen-caps to show my results.

Comment: would you be so kind to share this example as well, with the full screen scrollView? I'm not very familiar with using auto-layout by code.

Comment: @Hikarus - all I did was replaced the width/height/centerX/centerY constraints of the scroll view with top/bottom/leading/trailing constraints. I pushed the changes to my GitHub repo: https://github.com/DonMag/ZoomTest

Comment: I have remade the project from scratch, added a couple large images, and made a couple modifications to your code, notably, removing the 256 width and height constraints for the imageView, since I needed it to be the size of the scrollview, and they also seemed redundant. Everything works as I expected, except for the little detail that the image, which ever it is, always starts with an unrequested margin at the top, which disappears after zooming or panning. Any ideas of why this is happening?
Here's the GitHub repo: 
https://github.com/HikarusGF/ScrollView-ImageView-Zoom

Comment: By default, `UIScrollView` has `Content Insets: Automatic`, so the image view subview leaves space for the Safe Area. If you change that to `Never` (either in IB / Storyboard or via code with `ⓞscrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`), you won't get the "margin" at the top.

Comment: The bounty has ended, and I don't know if I have to do anything to get you those points or it's automatic... Le me know if there's something I ought to do, And thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So, in a couple words, the solution seems to be to add the ScrollView constraints on storyboard, ignore the nonsensical error, then on the viewController initialize a UIImageView property with a UIImage, and on viewDidLoad() add the imageView to the scrollView, and use NSLayoutConstraint's activate() method to set the imageView constraints relative to the scrollView's contentLayoutGuide, pinning it to the top, bottom, left, and right.

The implemented example is here:
https://github.com/HikarusGF/ScrollView-ImageView-Zoom

PS: I like to set the scrollView delegate on storyboard, so you won't see it in the code.

Comment: I posted this solution before I posted the storyboard solution, but for some reason it's being shown last.

Answer (score 0):

I FINALLY figured out how to implement this on storyboard, and make it way simpler. The way it used to be until a couple XCode versions ago:

We can still add a ScrollView on storyboard with they typical constraints to center vertical and horizontally to its superView, and equal width and height to the same, so the scrollView is seen in full screen.

So far so good, now comes the tricky part: Adding an ImageView, on storyboard as well, as a subView of the Scroll View. Here, the constraints we need are the FOUR THAT PIN THE IMAGEVIEW INSIDE THE SCROLLVIEW, but NEVER SIZE CONSTRAINTS. Should we use on the ImageView the same center/equal-size constraints used on the ScrollView, then when it comes to panning, and especially rotating the screen, the ScrollView will show an utterly erratical and nonsensical behavior.

We will still get the absurd storyboard warning/error telling us that our scrollView has “ambiguous content size”, and the “Update Frames” button will also have an erratic behavior, but we can ignore all that completely, and manually adjust the size of the ScrollView and the ImageView inside it, to look exactly as it will on runtime. NO EXTRA REDUNDANT CONSTRAINTS ARE NEEDED at all, especially nothing that touches the size of the ImageView.

The only code we need to add to our viewDidLoad() then, is the delegate method viewForZooming(), to inform the ScrollView of which subView to use as “zoomable”, in this case, our @IBOutlet UIImageView. The necessary minimum and maximum zoom scale parameters can be set on storyboard as well.

```
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? { return imageView }
```

Last, if we wish to get rid of the initial margins in the scrollView, since we’re just displaying a full screen image, we need to set this option I haven’t managed to find on the IB:

```
scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

Here’s the implanted project on GitHub: https://github.com/HikarusGF/ScrollView-ImageView-Zoom

Both code and storyboard solutions are implemented in the project. To switch from one to another just change the initial viewController on storyboard. I've set the storyboard solution as default.